# Gradle: Specify a merge strategy for duplicate files while copying

Tags: gradle

In Gradle there is a copy task where I can specify a `from`, a `into` and a `duplicatesStrategy`. However, the `duplicatesStrategy` is only an enum with limited options like `override`, `ignore` or `fail`.

Instead of just overriding I would like to be able to call a "content merge function" which takes the two files (the existing and the new one) as input parameters and outputs the resulting file.

```
from("fromdir") {
    into 'targetdir'
    duplicatesStrategy = { newFile,existingFile -> 
             return mergeFiles(newFile,existingFiles)
        }
}
```

Is that possible in any way?

Context: The task should copy doc book xml files from multiple projects into one. One Project can override parts of the documentation of another project, so there has to be some "logic" to merge the resulting documentation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it using

```
duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
```

Then in a separate task iterate and check for differences and handle the merge of them there. Preferably in an own task implementation using a third-party merge tool. My searches found no existing merge tasks.